# What is a "signal honor"?

Tags: meaning

In a [speech for the Collections as Data event](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gcu2GQf7PI&t=5h32m24s) at the Library of Congress, Maciej Cegłowski says this:

> As every speaker has correctly said, it is a signal honor to be here.

What is a '*signal honor*'?

Searching Google/MW did not yield any results.

Comment: "Signal honor" is an idiom that uses "signal" with a meaning that I've never seen used in any other contexts.  [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/signal_3) defines "signal" for this use: *especially important and noticeable*.

Comment: @HotLicks I think you need to get out more. *Signal victory*, *signal accmoplishment*

Comment: @deadrat - Yeah, "signal accomplishment" came to me after I posted that.  And I may have read "signal victory" once or twice, in old war stories.  But the usage is not common.

Comment: I realise I've probably heard "signal honour" before but mistaken it for "*singular* honour". Ahah, an [eggcorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn)!

Answer (score 2):

A [Google Search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=signal+honour&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari) returns six definitions on the first page.

> Especially important and noticeable:
>   a signal honour

([Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/signal_3))

Comment: If you just search for the definition of *signal*, however, you have to really know what you're looking for, to find that specific meaning.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, it is a rarer use, that's why I searched for "signal honour".

Comment: @HotLicks The Oxford online dictionary has [this definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/signal) of signal. There's only one definition of it as an adjective which is the one we're talking about.

Comment: @BoldBen - So a "signal flag" is a flag which is especially important?

Comment: @HotLicks I thought 'signal flag' was a compound noun.

Comment: @BoldBen - Only because it preserves your belief.

Answer (score 0):

I know from researching some military history that for certain actions in battle regiments can win "signal honors," meaning an award decorating their uniform. *Signaling* to viewers that this soldier carries a particular *honor*.

Comment: This would be a better answer with some supporting references.